# How do I create a log file for a WiX Installer?

Tags: file, installation, wix, logging

How do I create a log file for a WiX Installer?

I need to create a log file during installation of my installer created in [WiX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX). Currently I only know the commandline option to run the MSI file and generate a log file.

But I need to create a log file by running only the MSI file normally (not in commandline), and log each process happening during installation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The article *[How to enable Windows Installer logging](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223300)* explains how to enable Windows Installer logging for all MSI packages.

Comment: What I want to do is let the user install the msi file by running only the msi file.. not through a command line... I already know this one:
msiexec /I MySetup.msi /l*v <LogFile>

but how can I update my wix project so that it is automatically executed with a /l*v option

Comment: You can't. You would need a bootstrapper which launches the MSI with a logging command line.

Comment: can I implement this using custom action?

Comment: No, because the installation already started when the custom action runs. The possible solutions are a custom bootstrapper which uses the log command line or enable Windows Installer logging.

Answer (score 9):

If you're sure the machine on which your package will be installed will have MSI Installer 4.0 then you can set the MsiLogging property to your required logging options. See *[MsiLogging property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370322%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)*.

Which will automatically dump a file in your $TEMP folder.

It's not ideal, but it works.

Comment: can give me some sample of this. I am having a hard time looking for sample *.wxs file with MsiLogging property...

Comment: You set it the same way as any other property:

<Property Id="MsiLogging" Value="voicewarmup!"/>

Comment: Note: The MsiLogging property requires MSI 4.5 or greater.

Comment: @Christopher Do you have a source for that?  According to Microsoft it's available from 4.0 onwards.

Comment: You are correct, I forgot about MSI 4.0 It's kind of the forgotten MSI version as it's only available on Vista and only 4.5 is available on downlevel systems.  Either way the point is that if you are on a 2K3/XP machine with MSI 3.1 or older ( very common ) then it isn't going to work.